# javascript - limit active handlers amount

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html:

```
<div id="container" class="container">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

And css:

```
#container{
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.square{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}

.square:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.square--green{
  background: green;
}
```

Each `square` has a click handler on it. This handler makes clicked `square` green by adding a `square--green` css class. After 2 seconds, square gets back it's original color (class `square--green` removed in 2 sec via `setTimeout` in js). JS is:

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var children = container.children;

[].map.call(children, function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.classList.add('square--green');
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
      that.classList.remove('square--green');
    }, 2000)
  })
});
```

What I want to do is to allow having no more than two green squares at a time. So, if there are two green squares in the `container`, handlers for the rest of the squares must not get called.
After both green squares get their original color, all handlers should work again.
How to implement this ? I need pure js implementation.
Maybe my way of setting handlers to all squares is wrong ?
A pen: https://codepen.io/t411tocreate/pen/mqvGyJ

Comment: First, you should have just one event handler on the parent container instead of lot of equal event handlers. Second, you could create a counter variable in the parent scope - all event handler function instances have shared access to this variable in their lexical scope. Increase it when the event handler starts its work, decrease it when it's done, and check its value to decide if you want the event handler to do something or not.

Comment: Go read up on _event delegation_, and use _one_ click handler on the parent container element only. Inside that handler, either keep a counter of currently green elements, or count on the fly before coloring another one. (Have the timeout also decrease the counter, if you keep count yourself.)

Comment: @CBroe _"Inside that handler, either keep a counter"_ -- That will give you a fresh counter for each event handler call (because it creates a new execution context each time). It has to be in the parent lexical scope if you want to share it across different ev. handler calls.

Comment: @Mörre yeah thanks, that's what I meant more or less ... but considering this might probably not be the most performance critical thing to begin with, simply "counting" in-place using `getElementsByClassName().length` (on the container) might be an easier way to go.

Comment: @CBroe I disagree, since DOM operations are orders of magnitude(!) slower compared to pure JS - so even if it is not noticeable one should avoid it. After all, you also suggested (as I did) that he uses a single event handler on the parent, a similar optimization. Also, I don't see how a simple variable in the outer scope is any more difficult - quite the opposite IMO.

Comment: I meant on the knowledge/experience level the question suggests. // To keep this vanilla JS, I'd probably go with an IIFE returning the actual handler function, to create the necessary scope, that should keep it simple and self-contained.